# Calculate distance between column A and B pairs and present as matrix

Tags: python, pandas, distance

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['Bac 3','Bac 3','Bac 3'],
             'B':['Bac 6','Bac 6','Bac 8'],
             'A_len':[39577,39577,39577],
             'B_len':[40449,40449,38091],
             'A_prot_len':[500,550,800],
             'B_prot_len':[450,300,600]})

    A       B       A_len   B_len   A_prot_len  B_prot_len
0   Bac 3   Bac 6   39577   40449   500     450
1   Bac 3   Bac 6   39577   40449   550     300
2   Bac 3   Bac 8   39577   38091   800     600
```

The dataframe has been sorted by A and B whereby their order of occurrence is linked. I've made a function to calculate distances between unique pairs of A and B but would like to present the result in a matrix.

```
def dist_species(df):
    frames = []
    unique_B = list(set(df['B']))
    for species in unique_B:
        df = df.copy()
        A_B_pairs = df[df['B'] == species]
        x = {'A':'first','B':'first', 'A_len': 'first', 'B_len': 'first', 'A_prot_len':'sum', 'B_prot_len': 'sum'}
        A_B = A_B_pairs.groupby(['A','B']).agg(x).reset_index(drop=True)
        A_B['Dist'] = 1-(A_B['A_prot_len'] + A_B['B_prot_len']) / (A_B['A_len'] + A_B['B_len'])
        frames.append(A_B)
    return pd.concat(frames)
```

dist_species(df)

```
      A     B    A_len  B_len   A_prot_len  B_prot_len  Dist
0   Bac 3   Bac 6   39577   40449   1050    750     0.977507
0   Bac 3   Bac 8   39577   38091   800     600     0.981975
```

How can I structure my output to this:

```
|         | Bac 3   | Bac 6    | Bac 8    |
| --------| --------|----------|----------|        
| Bac 3   | 1       | 0.977507 | 0.981975 |        
| Bac 6   | 0.977507|   1      |   0      | 
| Bac 8   | 0.981975|   0      |   1      |
```

Really appreciate any guidance, thank you!

Comment: what do you mean distance between a and b?

Comment: @bpfrd distance using the formula A_B['Dist'] = 1-(A_B['A_prot_len'] + A_B['B_prot_len']) / (A_B['A_len'] + A_B['B_len'])

Comment: why the couple `Bac 3, Bac 6` is reported two times in `df`?

Comment: @SalvatoreDanieleBianco Hi, because there are 2 proteins shared between them and their lengths - A_prot_len and B_prot_len - need to be used in the distance formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first compute the distances for each couple in `A,B`:

```
computed_distances = df.groupby(["A", "B"])\
.agg({'A_len': 'first', 'B_len': 'first', 'A_prot_len':'sum', 'B_prot_len': 'sum'})\
.apply(lambda x:1-(x.A_prot_len+x.B_prot_len)/(x.A_len+x.B_len), axis=1)
```

The resulting `computed_distances` is a multi-index series:

```
A      B    
Bac 3  Bac 6    0.977507
       Bac 8    0.981975
dtype: float64
```

I also define a variable `bac` that contains all the Bacteria ID you have in `df`:

```
bac = np.unique([*df.A]+[*df.B])
```

After that I build the distance dataframe in the following way:

```
#first create a square Dataframe with bacteria IDs as both index and colums
#I unstack the dataframe to produce a multi-index series (like computed_distances series)
dist_df = pd.DataFrame(index=bac, columns=bac).unstack()

#then I fill the series with the computed distances
dist_df.loc[computed_distances.index] = computed_distances.values #dist_df(i,j) = computed_distances(i,j)
dist_df.loc[computed_distances.swaplevel(0,1).index] = computed_distances.values #dist_df(j,i) = computed_distances(i,j)


#I set to 1 the distances between the same bacteria    
dist_df.loc[dist_df.index.get_level_values(0)==dist_df.index.get_level_values(1)] = 1

#the remaining nan are the distances not computed
dist_df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

#finally return to the square dataframe shape
dist_df = dist_df.unstack()
```

The resulting `dist_df` is:

```
          Bac 3     Bac 6     Bac 8
Bac 3  1.000000  0.977507  0.981975
Bac 6  0.977507  1.000000  0.000000
Bac 8  0.981975  0.000000  1.000000
```

Comment: This is beautiful thank you!

Comment: You welcome. As bioinformatician it's always a pleasure to work on bioinformatics tasks.